# Work with session beans

Tags: java, javabeans

I have 2 session beans.

```
class A{
private Sting name;
}

class B{
}
```

How I can get A.name in B bean?

Comment: You can't, that is what `private` implies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the variable **public** in **Class A** and create an **object** for **Class A**
For Example

public class B {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    A testEx = new A();
    String testexample = testEx.name;
    System.out.print(testexample);
}
```

}

public class A{
    public String name;

}

Answer (score 0):

Set **Key** for **each bean class**, and call object of needed class using the **key** which already stored in session.